# Add many people from one form at a time And save in one table in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

When I click the register button all persons should be listed and stored in the user table.

I did a lot of research and they say that you should collect the information with the help of JavaScript and send it to the MVC action method. I do not know the code to do this. Please tell how I work with the view and action.

[Pleas see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eanvy.png)

```html
<tbody>
  <form action="/Home/paySalery" method="post">
    @foreach (var item in @Model.ProjectViewModels) {
      <tr>
        <td class="tablehead">@item.PersonName</td>
        <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px" name="workDay" /></td>
        <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 30px" name="AzafeKaryMinet" /></td>
        <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 30px" name="mamoriatDay" /></td>
        <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
    }
    <button class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit">ثبت حقوق</button>
  </form>
</tbody>
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult paySalery(PaySalery salery) 
{
  PaySalery paySalery = new PaySalery() 
  {
    PersonID = salery.PersonID,
      projectID = salery.projectID,
      hokmID = salery.hokmID,
      // ...
  };
  _context.Add(paySalery);
  _context.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("allPerson");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point is the `name` attribute:

```
<tbody>
    <form action="/Home/PaySalry" method="post">
        @for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            <tr style="display:block;">
                <td class="tablehead"></td>
                <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px" name="[@i].PersonID" /></td>
                <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px" name="[@i].ProjectID" /></td>
                <td><input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px" name="[@i].HokmID" /></td>
                <!-- ... -->
        </tr>
        }
        <button class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit">ثبت حقوق</button>
    </form>
</tbody>
```

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PaySalary(IEnumerable<PaySalary> salaries)
{
    //
    // do something to salaries
    //
    return RedirectToAction("AllPerson");
}
```

[Repo](https://github.com/ChrisWong979/AddManyPeople)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do not want to put a number in the loop I want to be the number of people in the model

Comment: please Chris Wong if you see my comment Answer me!!!!!!

Comment: Could you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#)? It could be easier to figure out the issue. You could refer to my [repo](https://github.com/ChrisWong979/AddManyPeople) on GitHub.